# Cannot convert 2 lines of code from Swift to Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use this library in my project: https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu

But I can't figure out how to implement this line of code in Objective C.
How can I write this in OBJ-C ?

```
menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {[weak self] (indexPath: Int) -> () in
    print("Did select item at index: \(indexPath)")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure I saw the exact same question yesterday and that someone (Martin R?) posted a link on how to solve it in the comments.

Comment: Yea, but after struggling again, I did not find a solution..

Comment: There's a website "www.fuckingblocksyntax.com" which may help. Yes, that's what it's called.

Comment: Well it's rude to just delete a question like that if someone has tried to help you, instead you should try to improve the question based on the help/comments you have gotten.

Comment: What to do when no one answers a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be like this

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
[self.menuView didSelectItemAtIndexHandler:^(Integer * _Nullable indexPath) {
  [weakSelf doWhatYouWant];
  printf("Did select item at index: %d", indexPath);
}];
```

I don't know the exact method here,

**edited**

try this I think this is the correct one:

```
menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = ^(NSUInteger indexPath){
        NSLog(@"Did select item at index: %ld", indexPath);
        self.selectedCellLabel.text = items[indexPath];
    };
```

Comment: Almost done, but I get `No visible @interface for 'PFNavigationDropdownMenu' declares the selector 'didSelectItemAtIndexHandler:'`. Thanks however!

Comment: The Objective-C version of BTNavigationDropdownMenu. Supports iOS 7.0+.

https://github.com/PerfectFreeze/PFNavigationDropdownMenu